# Prove that $F$ is locally constant iff the associated étale space over $X$ is a covering.

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

This is **Exercise II.5** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Locally%20constant%2C%20%C3%A9tale%20space%2C%20mac%20Lane%20and%20Moerdijk&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On p. 66, *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 1:** A *sheaf* of sets $F$ on a topological space $X$ is a functor $F:\mathcal{O}(X)^{{\rm op}}\to\mathbf{Sets}$ such that each open covering $U=\bigcup_iU_i, i\in I$, of open subsets of $U$ of $X$ yields an equaliser diagram
>
> $$ FU\stackrel{e}{\dashrightarrow}\prod_{i\in I}FU_i\overset{p}{\underset{q}{\rightrightarrows}}\prod_{i,j\in I}(U_i\cap U_j),$$
>
> where for $t\in FU,$ $e(t)=\{ t\rvert_{U_i}\mid i\in I\}$ and for a family $t_i\in FU_i$,
>
> $$p\{ t_i\}=\{t_i\rvert_{(U_i\cap U_j)}\}\quad\text{ and }\quad q\{ t_i\}=\{t_j\rvert_{(U_i\cap U_j)}\}.$$

From p. 79, *ibid.* . . .

> For any space $X$, a continuous map $p: Y\to X$ is called a *space over
> $X$* or a *bundle over $X$*.${}^\dagger$

From p. 82, *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 4:** A *covering map* $p: \stackrel{\sim}{X} \to X$ is a continuous map between topological spaces such that each $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$, with $x\in U \subset X$, for which $p^{-1}U$ is a disjoint union of open sets $U_i$, each of which is mapped [homeomorphically](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) onto $U$ by $p$.

On p. 88 *ibid*. . . .

> A bundle $p: E \to X$ is said to be *étale* (or *étale over $X$*) when $p$
> is a local homeomorphism in the following sense: To each $e\in E$ there is an open set $V$, with $e\in V\subset E$, such that $pV$ is open in $X$ and $p\rvert_V$ is a homeomorphism $V\to pV.$

From the exercise . . .

> **Definition:** A sheaf $F$ on a [locally connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LocallyConnected.html) space $X$ is *locally constant* if each point $x\in X$ has a basis of open neighborhoods $\mathcal{N}_x$ such that whenever $U, V \in\mathcal{N}_x$ with $U\subset V$, the restriction $FV\to FU$ is a bijection.

### The Question:

> Consider a sheaf $F$ on a locally connected space $X$. Prove that $F$ is locally constant iff the associated${}^{\dagger\dagger}$ étale space over $X$ is a covering.

### Thoughts:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $F$ be a sheaf on a locally connected space $X$. Suppose, further, that $F$ is locally constant. Let $x\in X$. Then there is a basis $\mathcal{N}_x$ such that, for any $U, V\in\mathcal{N}_x$ with $U\subset V$, the restriction $FU\to FV$ is a bijection.

What do I do now?

Looking at the definition of a sheaf, I find myself a little lost here.

$(\Leftarrow)$ I'm completely lost here. I'm not sure I understand the definition of an étale space.

### Further Context:

Related questions of mine include the following.

- [A sieve $S$ on $U$ in the category $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is principal iff the corresponding subfunctor $S\subset 1_U\cong{\rm Hom}(-,U)$ is a sheaf.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556625/104041)
- [A presheaf $P$ on $X$ is a sheaf iff for every covering sieve $S$ on an open set $U$ of $X$ one has $PU=\varprojlim_{V\in S}PV.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3557284/104041)

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: I'm assuming $Y$ is also a topological space. Am I right?

$\dagger\dagger$: I'm assuming this is the associated bundle as described on page 82, *ibid*, that, by hypothesis of the question, happens to be étale.

Comment: Intuition is that locally, sections of a covering space are determined by the choice of sheet/branch/fiber (assuming locally connected!). Since all fibers are the same for a covering space, that makes the sheaf of sections locally constant.

Comment: Just some advice for asking questions in the future, if someone has the answer to your question they most likely already know the definition of what a sheaf and a covering map is. You include too much background!

Comment: That's a fair comment, @NoelLundström. Thank you. I'd rather have too much background than not enough, though, and typing these things out helps me better understand them, at least partially. But still: I'll keep it in mind for the next few questions (if not all of them).

Comment: Note that the duplicate I suggested appeared on page 2 in your Approach0 search...

Comment: Thank you, @ArnaudD.; I'll endeavour to look further in future.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: first prove this for the constant sheaf, which corresponds to a trivial (disconnected) cover. This is the “local” version.

Side Note: $X$ must also be connected, else you can have different degree covers on different components and the sheaf still locally constant according to your definition.

Once you know the local version is true, Locally being the constant sheaf is the same as locally having trivial etale space which is definition of covering space (assuming $X$ connected to get evenly covered!). One way to go about proving that last part is to show the local version is functorial, which would imply that “local here corresponds to local there”, “locally (constant sheaf)” = “locally (trivial etale cover)”.

Comment: Coverings are often allowed to have different degrees on different components as well.

Comment: @jgon Thanks, thats better. I was remembering a definition from Munkres, but perhaps only connected spaces are treated.